# Why has there never been a T40 Track Race?

Tags: track-and-field, paralympics

I have had a look at some of the records for past Paralympics, and it looks like the T40 Track events have never been run?

For example in [2016](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athletics_at_the_2016_Summer_Paralympics_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_100_metres)

Is that data missing or have those events never run? If so, why?

Comment: I didn't found any T40 class under [Rio 2016 Paralympic Games
Qualification Guide](https://www.paralympic.org/sites/default/files/document/160523070735592_Rio%2BQG_23_May_2016.pdf) (page no. 8 onwards)